# Sending array through POST from React App to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, axios

I've already seen similar question with no success.
I need to send a matrix of numbers from a web app (ReactJS) to a Spring Boot controller.

I've tried many combination but it always get error, my payload is:

```
{"rows":[[7,0,0,6,4,0,0,0,0],[9,4,0,0,0,0,8,0,0],[0,8,6,2,5,0,0,9,0],[0,0,0,0,6,8,7,3,0],[4,0,8,0,2,1,0,0,0],[0,0,3,0,0,0,1,6,4],[0,0,0,0,0,9,6,7,5],[3,9,0,0,8,5,0,1,2],[0,0,5,0,0,4,0,0,0]]}
```

My react code is:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8090/api/check', {
        rows: this.props.rows
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

And my Spring Boot controller is:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/check")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public boolean check(@RequestParam(value = "rows") final int[] array, final int row, final int col, final int num) {
    return true;
}
```

I've already tried to declare `@RequestParam(value = "rows[]")` or `@RequestParam(value = "rows")`.
Rather than `@RequestParam(value = "rows") final Object rows`.

But it always respond with **error 400 (Bad request)**.

How can I pass a matrix through POST request?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you passing a huge payload in `RequestParam`? You should pass it in `RequestBody` of `POST` request instead.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri thanks for the reply, what do you mean? Are you talking about the `axios.post()` call? How can I pass it in the `RequestBody`?

Comment: Sorry but I am not aware about react but very much aware about Spring. Currently what you are doing is passing array in request parameter (query string) which is not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved wrapping all the parameter in just one Object.

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Params {

    private int[][] matrix;
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private int num;

    [...getters and setters]
```

And then declaring just one param in the sign of the method in the controller:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/check")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    public boolean check(@RequestBody final Params params) {
        return sudokuGenerator.checkValue(params.getMatrix(), params.getRow(), params.getCol(), params.getNum());
    }
```

Crucial, the client should pass the object with its atrtibutes, without any kind of wrapper, so in this way:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8090/api/check', {
     matrix: this.props.rows,
     "row": row - 1,
     "col": col - 1,
     "num": input.textContent
})
```

And not, in this way (with a root attribute "params"):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8090/api/check', {
     "params" : {
         matrix: this.props.rows,
         "row": row - 1,
         "col": col - 1,
         "num": input.textContent
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to turn your variable "rows" into a int[][] array, cause thats it what your json represents.

Also, in my spring webapplication i don't neccesarly need to declare a request parameter by annotation. Try to remove the Annotation (Spring will detect the parameter itself).
Also, remove all method parameter which are not included in the json (the request data).

```
@PostMapping(path = "/check")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public boolean check(int[][] array) {
    return true;
}
```

If you want to work with annotations, use @RequestBody for POST calls, @RequestParameter reads GET-Parameter (from URL like .../bla?param1rows=[[0,0]])

Comment: Thanks, with `@RequestBody` I get `Cannot deserialize instance of int[][]` it's a big step forward.