# Spring boot delete mapping array as paramater

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

I have the following controller method to get array of ids and then remove but what I send from react does not caught here.

```
@DeleteMapping({"delete-user"})
public GenericResponse deleteUser(@RequestBody String[] ids, Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors())
        throw new ParseException();
    return userService.delete(Arrays.asList(ids));
}
```

React request snippet

```
yield call(userDeleteService, payload.ids)
```

What payload is

```
callback: undefined
ids: Array(1)
    0: "08ddc3f3-9df3-463f-8d95-25a4633f24b7"
length: 1
```

This is the request that is sent from react side.

```
http://localhost:8080/user/delete-user?0=08ddc3f3-9df3-463f-8d95-25a4633f24b7&1=11036b08-8daa-44ef-a557-9723f20b8911&
```

Comment: The request should look like this : `http://localhost:8080/user/delete-user?ids=<id1>&ids=<id2>` etc... the request u currently have is wrong... `0` is an index for the FE but for the `java` it's nonsense and definitely not an item from the `ids` array.

Comment: so how can I handle this situation?

Comment: I have no react expertise and can't help much here...On prima vista found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990938/sending-array-through-post-from-react-app-to-spring-boot) but not sure if it will be helpful in any way... Try to dig a bit I guess is what you could do...

Comment: Why are you passing `ids` as parameters, that is really bad.Try @BogdanSucaciu solution that is the proper way to implement this

Answer (score 2):

Let's revise a bit your Endpoint.

You want to delete a user based on a list of ids:

1. You are exposing the endpoint using the DELETE verb which is
   perfect!
2. As part of good [REST practices](https://medium.com/hashmapinc/rest-good-practices-for-api-design-881439796dc9), you should use nouns instead of verbs in your endpoint definition. So exposing a DELETE endpoint at `/users` is better than exposing a DELETE endpoint `/users/delete-user`.
3. Make sure that from the front'end you are actually using the `DELETE` verb and not GET, POST or anything else.
4. It seems that you are sending the ids through 2 different methods: body and query param, choose one! I would choose the body since your desired result is to send multiple objects at a time.

To retrieve a list of ids you should wrap your array in a class:

```
public class DeleteUserDTO {
  private List<String> ids;

  // getter  + setter
}
```

And then use this object as the request body:

```
@DeleteMapping
public GenericResponse deleteUser(@RequestBody DeleteUserDTO dto, Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors())
        throw new ParseException();
    return userService.delete(dto.getIds());
}
```